# Inserting multiple same named field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Please help. I did some working code i found here in forum but i think there is something wrong with it. And no data inserted in my database (description and quantity)
Here is my php code:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "posharrison";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$dbname")or die("cannot select DB");

$branch=$_POST['branch'];
$mydate=$_POST['mydate'];
$product=$_POST['product'];

$description = implode(',',$_POST['description']);
$quantity = implode(',',$_POST['quantity']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO orderlist (`description`,
`quantity`) VALUES ('".$description."', '".$quantity."')"; 

$sql = "INSERT INTO orderlist (branch, date, pname)
VALUES ('$branch', '$mydate', '$product')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
echo "<script>
        alert('Success');
        window.location ='./order.php';
        </script>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR!!".die(mysql_error());
}
?> 
<?php 
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

And here my html code:

```
<div class="desktop box" style="display:none">
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;Select Item:
                                    <select name="description[]">
                                            <option>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</option>
                                            <option>Dell corei7 2500 1gRAM 80gHDD COMBO</option>
                                            <option>Green</option>
                                            <option>Blue</option>
                                    </select>
                                    &nbsp;Quantity:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="quantity[]" size="8">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="monitor box" style="display:none">
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;Select Item:
                                    <select name="description[]">
                                            <option>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</option>
                                            <option>monitor</option>
                                            <option>Green</option>
                                            <option>Blue</option>
                                    </select>
                                    &nbsp;Quantity:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="quantity[]" size="8">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="laptop box" style="display:none">
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;Select Item:
                                    <select name="description[]">
                                            <option>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</option>
                                            <option>laptop</option>
                                            <option>Green</option>
                                            <option>Blue</option>
                                    </select>
                                    &nbsp;Quantity:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="quantity[]" size="8">
                                    </div>  
                                    <div class="parts box" style="display:none">
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;Select Item:
                                    <select name="description[]">
                                            <option>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</option>
                                            <option>parts</option>
                                            <option>Green</option>
                                            <option>Blue</option>
                                    </select>
                                    &nbsp;Quantity:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="quantity[]" size="8">
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Yeah, you're doing what B-and-P said below. Plus, you're open to SQL injection. Do use prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting your query before this line:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

You should run both queries:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orderlist (`description`,
`quantity`) VALUES ('".$description."', '".$quantity."')"; 
 $result=mysql_query($sql);

$sql = "INSERT INTO orderlist (branch, date, pname)
VALUES ('$branch', '$mydate', '$product')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Dang didnt see someone posted already

Answer (score 0):

Please attempt to check your code before posting to StackOverflow.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orderlist (`description`,
`quantity`) VALUES ('".$description."', '".$quantity."')"; 

$sql = "INSERT INTO orderlist (branch, date, pname)
VALUES ('$branch', '$mydate', '$product')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Your issue is your SQL variable.